# Can we write a "libstdc++" wrapper over a "libc++" library to link and build it with a "libstdc++" project?

Tags: xcode, macos, c++11, libstdc++

I am building a project in Xcode in my mac machine. There are many project librarires which need libstdc++ to compile successfully; I need to compile a third party code with my project which uses libc++ libraries(boost, openssl etc).

I need to know if I can write a wrapper over my third party source code so that I can build my project successfully keeping the libstdc++ in standard library setting in Xcode.

OS version: macOS Sierra (version 10.12)
Xcode version: 8.1

Comment: I think you cannot link both versions at the same time. But what you could do is to "wrap" the components requiring a different C++ library version into a shared library and link that one to your application. So you will have a shared library that links itself to libstdc++ and an application that links to libc++ and your shared library. Or vice versa.

Comment: ok..so I have to write another implementation which will wrap all the functions I am using from the libc++ library?

Comment: In worst case you need to write a wrapper for these symbols, yes. If they all are C interfaces you may be able to create a shared library from the things you have directly.